# AWS SDK S3 Upload Credentails

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I have followed this tutorial (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html) from AWS for setting up the AWS sdk iOS 9 app using swift and xcode.  I am trying to upload a file to an S3 bucket.

I added the following code to the AppDelegate.swift file
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1,identityPoolId:"mypoolid")

let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

I also included the code snippet in the Info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
<dict>
    <key>amazonaws.com</key>
    <dict>
          <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.0</string>
          <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
          <false/>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>amazonaws.com.cn</key>
    <dict>
          <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
          <string>TLSv1.0</string>
          <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
          <false/>
          <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
          <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

but I get this error.  If it wants me to put credentials in Info.plist how would I do this?...or am I doing something else wrong?  Thank you in advance for help.

```
AWSServiceInfo initWithInfoDictionary:checkRegion:] | 
Couldn't read credentials provider configurations from `Info.plist`. 
Please check your `Info.plist` if you are providing the SDK configuration values through `Info.plist`.
```

Comment: You are not providing the configuration through `Info.plist`. Instead, you are using `defaultServiceConfiguration`. You can safely ignore the message.

Comment: Sorry for the short answer, I can't comment due to low rep. I am not sure it is your case, but I was missing the region when I set up the identity pool in my app. Your identityPoolId in app delegate should also include it. Try: let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId:"us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")

Comment: Thaks for your comment....I just typed in "mypoolid" as an example

Answer (score 0):

My problem was file wasn't uploading to S3 bucket...there was something wrong in the credential settings...in the serviceConfiguration it had the incorrect region in which the bucket was created...once i changed that the file was uploaded.